# Cant access User Entity Fields that implements UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

So i have this entity on spring boot

```
@Table(name = "user_table")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;
private String name;

private String email;

private String password;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_course",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
)
private List < Course > courses;

public List < Course > getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(List < Course > courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@Override
public Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority > getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

}
```

im following  amigoscode tutorial on jwt/spring security [amigo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxqlJblhzfI)

```
public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
var user = User.builder()
    .name(request.getName()) //catnt acces this name field
    .email(request.getEmail()) //catnt acces this name field    
    .password(request.getPassword()) // i can access this filed
    .role(request.getRole()) //i can access this field
    ......

 }
```

i noticed that it can only access the fields from UserDetails but not the fields of my entity,
is there some anotation i missed on my entity or the problem is somehwhere else

thank you for you attention

i want to access the fields of my entity

Answer (score 0):

Just combing through the code on that repo of the tutorial you are following, the only thinking I can think of is that possibly your **User.builder()** in the register function is referencing the package "**org.springframework.security.core.userdetails**" instead of your own project package.

Answer (score 0):

It would implement two different classes, User class and CustomUserDetails class,which CustomUserDeatails extend User class and implement UserDetail.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

+ getters and setters
```

and then define CustomUsetDetails,

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Users user;

public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
    super(user);
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
   
    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN");
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // just for example
    return this.user.getActive() == true;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.user.getUsername();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.user.getPassword();
}

// Just an example to put some addititional Data to your logged in user

public String getUserDatabase() {
    return "usertable" + Integer.toString(1 + this.user.getUserId());
}
}
```